# how to create your COM interface on python?

Tags: python, com

I need to create a COM interface as well as a component. How do I create an interface using comtypes?

Comment: you've read the actual official documentation already, https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/ ?

Comment: yes, but I still haven't figured out how to create an interface for this to work

Comment: please try to narrow down your question. The way it's stated now is really inanswerable. If the official documentation with its examples is not what you're looking for, it's not clear what you'd be looking for.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.